# Javascript to auto click on multiple id settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a problem.
I want to click on `$(document).ready(function()` to `id="menu1"` in 5 seconds after the page is loaded one after the other click function (click to menu1 wait 5 sec and then click to menu2 wait 5 sec etc.) and then repeat the click from `id="menu1"`.

HTML:

```
<a id="menu1">
<div class="menu1">
<div class="menu1text">
TEXT
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a id="menu2">
<div class="menu2">
<div class="menu2text">
TEXT
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a id="menu3">
<div class="menu3">
<div class="menu3text">
TEXT
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
    $( "#menu1" ).click(function() {
    $('.menu1').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu2').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu1text').css('color', '#000000');
    $('.menu2text').css('color', '#000000');

    });

$( "#menu2" ).click(function() {
    $('.menu1').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu2').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu1text').css('color', '#000000');
    $('.menu2text').css('color', '#000000');

    });

$( "#menu3" ).click(function() {
    $('.menu1').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu2').css('background-color', '#d9cbb3');
    $('.menu1text').css('color', '#000000');
    $('.menu2text').css('color', '#000000');

    });
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = 1;
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#menu' + i).click();
        i = i == 3 ? 1 : (i + 1);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to run a function every 5 seconds, and increment a counter variable to point to a different menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#menu"+counter+1).click();
        counter = (counter + 1)%3;
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(clickMenu, 5000, 1);

function clickMenu(n){$("#menu" + n).click(); window.setTimeout(clickMenu, 5000, n==3?1:n+1);}
```

Comment: I meant it was for infinite number of `menu`s. While the OP has only 3.